# Does the following conditions ensure the infinite set B is enumerable?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, natural-numbers

Let $B$ be an infinite set.

Suppose we take input set as $B$ and output set as $\mathbb{N}$

(1) $∀\ b∈ B, ∃!\ n∈ \mathbb{N}, \text{output $(b)$ is $n$}$

This ensures $f:B→N$ exist.

(2) $∀\ n∈ \mathbb{N}, ∃!\ b∈ B, f(b)=n$

Does this ensure $B$ is enumerable ?

Comment: Sets cannot be "bijective."  Functions may be.

Comment: I take it $f$ is a function from $B\to N$?  But, if that's the case, the first line is not needed.  All functions are single valued.  The second condition does imply that $f$ is both surjective and injective, hence bijective.

Comment: For countability you should specify that $N$ is the set of natural numbers (or some other countably infinite set). As a matter of notation, writing $\mathbb N$ is broadly accepted to denote the natural numbers, the syntax being \mathbb N

Comment: @lulu: So first line ensures $f:B→\mathbb{N}$ exist. Second line imply $f:B→\mathbb{N}$ is both injective and surjective. AM I CORRECT ?

Comment: You should say what $f$ is, your post leaves that off.  I took it to denote a function from a set $B$ to a set $N$, but you should say that.  Or, if you meant something else, you should be clear about that.  As for the second line, sticking with my interpretation of $f$, you say that each value in the range is hit by $f$ exactly once, and that's the definition of a bijection.

Comment: Not following.  I took it that $f$ was assumed to exist.  If you haven't got $f$, then I don't know what either line is saying.

Comment: Edited..... Please have a look. After (1), we ensure $f:B→N$ exist.

Comment: It seems odd.  Is there a reason not  to just say "let $f$ be a function from $B$ to $\mathbb N$"?  I don't know what "input" and "output" are without something like a function.

Comment: Yes, there is reason. In my original problem, we are first constructing $f:B→N$ from sets $B$ and $\mathbb{N}$. To ensure that we have completed our construction of $f:B→N$, we need to prove (1). After that, we prove (2) to ensure our constructed $f:B→N$ is 
bijective.  Thus we have proved set $B$ is enumerable.

So, is my question correct ?

Comment: I think there's too  much missing context and assumptions.  I suggest adding in what one knows about $f$.  Presumably you have something like a function from $B$ to...well, maybe sets of natural numbers or multisets, or something like that.  And then you add conditions to ensure that this is actually a function.  But we can't really guess from the terse description.

Comment: what keeps every b from mapping to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there exists a function with the attributes (1) and (2) you stipulated, then $B$ is indeed enumerable (i.e. “countable”). But note that this is not determined by $B$ alone. The countability of $B$ also depends on what ***functions*** are assumed to exist.

If you’re working in a set theory like $\mathsf{ZFC}$, it’s possible that in one model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, call it $\mathfrak{M}_{1}$, the requisite function exists (thus “according to $\mathfrak{M}_{1}$” $B$ is countable), but in a transitive submodel $\mathfrak{M}_{2}$ no such function exists (thus “according to $\mathfrak{M}_{2}$” $B$ is ***un***countable)

This “relativity” of notions like countability is one tricky aspect of set theory that’s not always well explained in introductory treatments (but it follows as a consequence of the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem on the existence of countable models)